Why after n=int(input()) I input 1,2,3,4,5 or 6 and Jupyter convert my code to markdown and nothing else
Why after n=int(input()) I input 1,2,3,4,5 or 6 and Jupyter convert my code to markdown and nothing else?
But if I input 9, 19, 18, 222 etc it's ok
My python version Python 3.12.0
I'm expecting good job for every integer. Thank you in advance.

I suspect it could be related to this issue; however, you do not specify your version of Jupyter. Only Python version number is supplied. Please be more thorough in providing details.
